# Let $|G|=2n$. Let half of the elements of $G$ be of order $2$, and other half form a subgroup $H$ of order $n$. Prove $|H|$ is odd and $H$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I find a problem in 'Topics in Algebra' by I.N. Herstein

"Let $G$ be a group of order $2n$. Suppose half of the elements of $G$ are of order $2$, and other half form a subgroup $H$ of order $n$. Prove that $H$ is of odd order and is an abelian group."

I have done the first part that if $H$ is of even order then it has an element of order $2$ and then $G$ will have more than half elements of order $2$. But I am unable to do other part, please help.

Also I have another thing in my mind. Is $G$ necessarily a dihedral group? Prove or disprove.

Comment: Your subject line does not match the question you ask. The group you want to prove abelian is $H$, which is of order $n$.

Comment: Yes we have to H is abelian and I don't find any error in my subject line.

Comment: Your subject line says "a group of order 2n is abelian".  $G$ has order $2n$. The group you want to prove is abelian is $H$, which has order $n$, not $2n$. Do you really not see that?

Comment: The dihedral group is nonabelian.

Comment: The abelianess refers to the subgroup $H$, @Shaun. The title is misleading.

Comment: And such groups in the corrected title are called *generalized dihedral*.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: fix an $s \in G$ of order $2$, so $s=s^{-1}$. Show that for any $h \in H$, $s^{-1}hs=h^{-1}$. Then calculate for $h,k \in H$ the product $ s^{-1}hks$ in two ways: $s^{-1}hks=(s^{-1}hs) \cdot (s^{-1}ks)$.

Comment: The product gives $shks=h^{-1}k^{-1}$, equivalently, $shkskh=e$, but how to show it is Abelian?

Comment: @GGplay First show that $s$ flips each $h \in H$ to its inverse $h^{-1}$ under conjugation. Have you done that? And then what is $s^{-1}(hk)s$?

Comment: I see, it gives $(hk)^{-1}$, thank you!

Comment: Yes, so we already knew $(hk)^{-1}=h^{-1}k^{-1}$ but also $(hk)^{-1}=k^{-1}h^{-1}$. Hence for all $h,k \in H$ we have $ h^{-1}k^{-1}=k^{-1}h^{-1}$, equivalent to $kh=hk$ for all $h,k \in H$, that is $H$ is abelian.